# Computed column in SELECT CASE t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got a computed column:

```
BilledAmount = 
    CASE 
        WHEN CoverageItem  in ('MED','RNB', 'LAB')  
            THEN  ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(hb.BilledAmt,0)),0)
        END
    FROM HospitalBill hb with(nolock)
```

Basically, what it does is sum up the amount billed with a coverage item of for example MED from the HospitalBill table...What I wan't to do is to add another case which if the CoverageItem = 'BEN'... then the BilledAmount would be the sum of the BilledAmounts with the CoverageItem of 'LAB' and 'BEN'.. is that possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  ProviderCode, 
  CASE
    WHEN CoverageItem IN ('LAB', 'BEN') THEN 'LAB'
    ELSE CoverageItem
  END AS CoverageItem,
  SUM(hb.BilledAmt) AS BilledAmount
FROM HospitalBill hb
Group BY 
  ProviderCode, 
  CASE
    WHEN CoverageItem IN ('LAB', 'BEN') THEN 'LAB'
    ELSE CoverageItem
  END
```

Comment: Glad, I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Sum should be outside your case statement. i.e.

```
SUM(
CASE 
    WHEN CoverageItem  in ('MED','RNB', 'LAB')  
        THEN  ISNULL(hb.BilledAmt,0)
    ELSE
        0
    END
FROM HospitalBill hb with(nolock)) as BilledAmount
```

Comment: If you could provide some example values an the result you are trying to achieve based on those values, that may be helpful.

Comment: SAMPLE TABLE: Copy this on a notepad for clearer view.
ProviderCode       CoverageItem        BilledAmount
001     MED         100
001            MED         100
002                RNB                 200
003                LAB                 300
003                BEN                 500

OUTPUT TABLE
ProviderCode       CoverageItem        BilledAmount
001     MED         200
002                RNB                 200
003                LAB                 800